# moving the directories using find command

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am trying to find particular directory in one path and move the directory in other path using find.

Source directory looks like below,

```
/Dir1/country1/month1/date1,date2,date3
/Dir1/country2/month1/date1,date2,date3
...
.
.
/Dir1/country10/month1/date1,date2,date3
```

I am trying to find date1 directory and move to destination

> /Backup/source1/Dir1/

I am using below command

> [root@mytest Dir1]# find -name "date1" -exec mv {}
>   /Backup/source1/Dir1/{} \;

and I am getting below error.

> **mv: failed to preserve ownership for
>   `/Backup/source1/Dir1/./country1/month1/date1/date1/date1_1.txt':
>   Operation not permitted**

Not sure how to remove duplication of date1 Directory in destination and **"./"** is also creating issue.

Best Wishes,
KJ

Comment: The error you are getting implies either not running with the correct permissions or the target filesystem is not capable of handling the permissions.  Why not rejig your find command to do a cp and rm.

Answer (score 0):

The [Linux Man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) states:

> mv - move (rename) files

Thus you cannot use `mv` to move a directory. You may however, first copy it then erase the old copy.This command

```
   SRC_DIR=$(find . -type d -name date1 -print); echo $SRC_DIR
```

will store the relative path to the directory you are interested in, in a convenient variable. Now we can make the directory in the new position,

```
   mkdir /Backup/source1/$SRC_DIR
```

provided you have the authority to do so: in fact, the error message above is about your having insufficient proivileges to create a new file (it should have been a folder, but became a file because of the error above). Are you sure the new  /Backup/dir1 belongs to you? You should check that, and fix it.

Now you can recursively cp all content to the new directory:

```
   cp -R $SRC_DIR/* /Backup/dir1/$SRC_DIR
   cp -R $SRC_DIR/.[a-Z]* /Backup/dir1/$SRC_DIR
```

and lastly, you caan erase the old copy, if you have to:

```
   cd $SRC_DIR
   rm -fR *
   rm -fR .[a-Z]*
```

and now the directory is empty and can be erased.

Comment: thanks for the inputs. I am running the command as root user and destination directory is own by root only. I have many directory  which i need to move and of huge size, so was looking a process to automate

Comment: @KJT Do the commands I suggested work?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using move which is a Blunt tool, check out rsync which can shift directory trees in archive mode which preserves permissions and both soft & hard symbolic links.

Also if you type `updatedb` as root it will update the `locate` database of files that are in the various path trees of installed packages. Binaries, man pages and Source trees. Searching with `whereis` or `locate` is much faster than doing the actual disk search each time.